# CodeIgniter - adds an extra class to my URL when i click on a link

Tags: codeigniter

I'm new in CI as well in php. I have a problem that's bugging me for two days now:

when i click on a link in my admin header(say: Articles) it takes me to: www.example.com/admin/articles, which is ok. If now i try to click on another link in the header (say: Add articles), the url becomes: www.example.com/admin/admin/add_articles - it adds an extra admin to my url. if i click again on Articles, the url will be: www.example.com/admin/admin/admin/articles, and so on.

Do you have any idea why is this happening?
Thanks

Comment: user absolute urls not relative, use $config['base_url'] before every link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 choice, the first is that you wrote in every link base_url() 
OR
you can use a built in helper:

```
anchor('route','label','attributes')
```

in your example:

```
anchor('admin/add_article','Add an article',array('class' => 'link'))
```

Then that will create this HTML code:

```
<a href="what is your base_url value/admin/add_article" class="link">Add an article</a>
```

Comment: I use always the anchor(), because with this, if I upload to an other location my code, I only have to change the config file for the new URL. And please accept my answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use absolute urls not relative, use $config['base_url'] before every link

Answer (score 0):

Don't use

```
$config['base_url] . 'controller/action',
```

use the function:

```
site_url('controller/action');
```

Or use the anchor function @András Rátz suggested.